# standard main and unicode, managing console input and output

Tags: c++, string, winapi, unicode, program-entry-point

The standard recognizes `int main()` and `int main(int, char* [])` entry points, and there is no unicode version of the function, except of course if provided by implementation such as `wmain` on windows.

I have code which strictly uses 'wide' strings ie. `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` not even a single LOC makes any use of `char` type.

Also all the 'program output' is printed with `std::wcout`.

Now I do understand when the program starts it's stream will be set to 'wide' stream, and even if somewhere in the code `std::cout` appears instead of `std::wcout` then output may be wrong.

Now my first misunderstanding is, if a user runs several command line tools in same terminal (ie. cmd.exe) where one program uses wide string and other uses ASCII strings then what is the behavior of the terminal?

Does it handle both streams just fine? is wide stream and non wide stream related to program and not to terminal?

Secondly, my main issue is that my 'unicode' program expects user input, which will most likely be `char` because `int main(int, char* [])` accepts `char` string, but my code uses `wide` strings.

What are my options here? do I need to convert input non unicode strings to wide strings?

And what happens if I use `int wmain(int, wchar_t* [])` on windows? how do I know if terminal will interpret user input as wide characters and forward them to my entry point?

what if user copy/pastes ASCII string into the console as input to my entry point?

So my questions are, console program input and output char and wchar_t in both portable and non portable code, missing wide main function by standard is what confuses me most in combination with different terminals.

**edit**

To be clear,

1. I want to use standard `main` and wide strings.
2. my code uses wide string.
3. my program expects user input, and writes output. so how to best handle this?
4. Is `wmain` the only solution to get unicode input and how do terminals work in regard to unicode vs non unicode with different programs in same console session.

Comment: See _"...argv...point to null-terminated multibyte strings that..."_ (including UTF-8) in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function linked to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte  What does your console support?

Comment: I took a read, and obviously we need to use locale specific functions to determine what kind of a string is given as input. `What does your console support?` I don't know how `cmd` and `powershell` work with strings and what encoding they use, I think I'll just limit my program to accept normal `char`and do conversion to `wchar_t` with MS specific functions to forward input string to the rest of the code.

Comment: even though If I use `wmain` and test the program in `cmd.exe` the input I type on command line is given as `char`, so what's the point of `wmain`? I just cant google out all the information to answer all my questions regarding this. utf8, utf16, ASCII, different terminals etc.. there is no damn standard, just bunch of articles.

Comment: Unicode standard with `wmain` is fine. WinAPIs use UTF16 internally. APIs such as `CreateProcessA` will use ANSI input, then convert ANSI to UTF16, then pass UTF16 to `wmain`, or it's converted back to ANSI and passed to `main`. You can print UTF8 in console, but you can't paste UTF8 text in to console window.

Comment: [wmain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/using-wmain) receives a `wchar_t*`, not a `char*`.